# android retrace proguard (build api 23)

Tags: android, android-proguard

I recently started using proguard in my project.
I created test crash (in App class)
I received next error -

```
 03-23 10:12:26.030 4956-4956/social.game.dating E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 java.lang.NullPointerException
 at social.game.dating.App.App.m(Unknown Source)
 at social.game.dating.App.App.l(Unknown Source)
 at social.game.dating.App.App$a.a(Unknown Source)
 at social.game.dating.App.App$a.onPostExecute(Unknown Source)
 at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
 at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
 at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I run script

```
 java -jar retrace.jar -verbose d:/mapping.txt d:/obf.txt > d:/fixed.txt
```

to obfuskate code, and receive next:

```
 03-23 10:12:26.030 4956-4956/social.game.dating E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 java.lang.NullPointerException
 at social.game.dating.App.App.void initSync()(Unknown Source)
 at social.game.dating.App.App.void access$100()(Unknown Source)
 at social.game.dating.App.App$InitTask.java.lang.Void doInBackground(java.lang.Void[])(Unknown Source)
 void onPostExecute(java.lang.Void)
 at social.game.dating.App.App$InitTask.void onPostExecute(java.lang.Object)(Unknown Source)
 at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
 at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
 at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

So I just received method, in wich exception was caught. I would like to get the line, if it is possible, please help!

PS also, I tried

```
 retrace.bat -verbose d:/mapping.txt d:/obf.txt > d:/out.txt
```

and received the same result

Comment: I just found if I add -keepattributes ** than I get proper line number

Answer (score 1):

You need to add next rule to proguard config file:

```
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
```

If you want to hide actual source file name add next rule:

```
-renamesourcefileattribute SomeName
```

and all file names will be renamed to SomeName.java, but after deobfuscation you will have class name and line number which will allow you to restore actual line of code

Comment: what if I use -keepattributes ** ? I will keep smth else, which would be better to obuskate/rename?

Comment: @AntonKizema It will keep all possible attributes, full list is here http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/attributes.html but I don't think that keeping all of them is a great idea.